# Как сделать изменяемый размер text в matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я установил размер текста и задал ему координаты появления. При запуске кода, текс отображается как надо:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но, когда я уменьшаю график, текс накладывается друг на друга:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы размер текста изменялся при изменении размера осей X и Y?

Мой код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

box_1 = {'facecolor':'black',    #  цвет области
       'edgecolor': 'red',     #  цвет крайней линии
       'boxstyle': 'square', #  стиль области
       }    

xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = [0.2, 0.4, 0.5]

for i, i2 in zip(xs, ys):
    ax.text(i, i2, "55555 |  198  |1, 3, 5", 
            bbox = box_1, 
            color = 'white',
            size='x-small')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.xlim (0, 5) # Первоначальное отображение диапазона x
plt.show()
```